# c++ Multithreaded output freezes on join()

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance

This is a mock up of code I have for output drivers which output to files, database, etc.
In the array in main, if I have two objects of the same child type, the code stalls out on the second call to `ShutDown()`. However, If I have two objects of different child types it does not stall out, exiting the program correctly. I have no idea what is causing the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent();
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    virtual void ShutDown() = 0;

    void Push(int aInt);
    virtual void Write(int aInt) = 0;
    bool IsEmpty() { return mList.empty(); }
protected:
    std::list<int> Pop();
    void WriteWithThread();
    std::list<int> mList;
    std::thread mOutputThread;
    std::condition_variable mCV;
    std::mutex mMutex;
    std::atomic_bool mProgramRunning{ true };
    std::atomic_bool mThreadRunning{ false };

};

Parent::Parent()
{
    mOutputThread = std::move(std::thread(&Parent::WriteWithThread, this));
}

void Parent::Push(int aInt)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
    mList.emplace_back(std::move(aInt));
    lock.unlock();
    mCV.notify_one();
}

std::list<int> Parent::Pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
    mCV.wait(lock, [&] {return !mList.empty(); });
    std::list<int> removed;
    removed.splice(removed.begin(), mList, mList.begin());
    return removed;
}

void Parent::WriteWithThread()
{
    mThreadRunning = true;
    while (mProgramRunning || !mList.empty())
    {
        Write(Pop().front());
    }
    mThreadRunning = false;
}

class ChildCout : public Parent
{
public:
    ChildCout() = default;
    void ShutDown() override;
    void Write(int aInt) override;
};

void ChildCout::ShutDown()
{
    mProgramRunning = false;
    if (mOutputThread.joinable())
    {
        mOutputThread.join();
    }
    std::cout << "Shutdown Complete"<< std::endl;
}
void ChildCout::Write(int aInt)
{
    std::cout << "Inserting number: " << aInt << std::endl;
}
class ChildFile : public Parent
{
public:
    ChildFile(std::string aFile);
    void ShutDown() override;
    void Write(int aInt) override;
private:
    std::fstream mFS;
};

ChildFile::ChildFile(std::string aFile):Parent()
{
    mFS.open(aFile);
}

void ChildFile::ShutDown()
{
    mProgramRunning = false;
    if (mOutputThread.joinable())
    {
        mOutputThread.join();
    }
    mFS.close();
    std::cout << "Shutdown Complete" << std::endl;
}

void ChildFile::Write(int aInt)
{
    mFS<< "Inserting number: " << aInt << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Parent *array[] = {new ChildFile("DriverOutput.txt"),new ChildFile("Output2.txt"), new ChildCout()};

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        for (auto& child : array)
        {
            child->Push(i);
        }
    }
    for (auto& child : array)
    {
        child->ShutDown();
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(x.joinable()) { x.join(); }` is an anti-pattern. If you actually need to check if `x` is joinable, then you have a sort of race where `x` may become non-joinable after the `if` but before the `join()`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good to know, Having the check doesn't really change the behavior of the freezing though. I have the check because I was trying to debug really

Comment: Note: `mOutputThread = std::move(std::thread(&Parent::WriteWithThread, this));` you don't have to use `std::move` here; `std::thread(&Parent::WriteWithThread, this)` is already an xvalue. Furthermore `mCV.wait(lock, [&] {return !mList.empty(); });` should imho be `mCV.wait(lock, [this] {return !mList.empty(); });`...

Comment: @fabian I made the changes you suggested, however it didn't effect the outcome.

Comment: @dogtail1011 The comments in this section are usually not meant to be answers to the problem or question you asked. If they were, they would have been posted as answers below instead. Rather, these comments are general advice to improve your code or to share information you might otherwise find useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never notify the thread about the shutdown and the predicate doesn't even consider, whether `mProgramRunning` has been set to false. You need to notify the condition variable after writing `mProgramRunning` you need to change the predicate accordingly.

E.g. something like this should work, but I consider the separation of the `Pop` and the `WriteWithThread` functions suboptimal, since the signatures force you to add unnecessary reads to `mProgramRunning`.

```
...

std::list<int> Parent::Pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
    //mCV.wait(lock, [&] {return !mList.empty(); });
    bool running = true;
    mCV.wait(lock, [this, &running] { // member variables accessed via this pointer -> capture this by value
        running = running = mProgramRunning.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        return !running || !mList.empty(); // need to check for shutdown here too
    });

    std::list<int> removed;
    if (running)
    {
        removed.splice(removed.begin(), mList, mList.begin());
    }
    return removed;
}

void Parent::WriteWithThread()
{
    mThreadRunning = true;
    while (mProgramRunning)
    {
        auto list = Pop();
        if (list.empty())
        {
            break;
        }
        Write(list.front());
    }
    mThreadRunning = false;
}

...

void ChildCout::ShutDown()
{
    mProgramRunning.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    mCV.notify_all(); // tell consumer about termination
    if (mOutputThread.joinable())
    {
        mOutputThread.join();
    }
    std::cout << "Shutdown Complete" << std::endl;
}

...

void ChildFile::ShutDown()
{
    mProgramRunning.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    mCV.notify_all(); // tell consumer about termination
    if (mOutputThread.joinable())
    {
        mOutputThread.join();
    }
    mFS.close();
    std::cout << "Shutdown Complete" << std::endl;
}

...
```

Note: I'm not 100% sure this does what exactly you expect it to do, but it should give you an idea what went wrong.

---

A note on `std::move`: This is only useful to turn something not assignable to an rvalue reference into something that is assignable to an rvalue reference.

In

```
mOutputThread = std::move(std::thread(&Parent::WriteWithThread, this));
```

it's unnecessary to use `std::move`, since `std::thread(&Parent::WriteWithThread, this)` is an xvalue which is assignable to an rvalue reference, so

```
mOutputThread = std::thread(&Parent::WriteWithThread, this);
```

is sufficient.

You'd need use `std::move`, if the thread object "had a name":

```
std::thread tempThread(&Parent::WriteWithThread, this);
mOutputThread = std::move(tempThread);
```

Furthermore in

```
mList.emplace_back(std::move(aInt));
```

it's not necessary to use `std::move` either, copy and move assignment for `int` have the same effect. Arithmetic types don't benefit from the use of `std::move`.

Comment: I think this is on the right track. The condition variable seems to be causing a deadlock.
This solution will cause the threads to exit before all the lists are fully empty though, meaning not all the data is output.

Comment: With some tweaking, this fixed my problem. 
All your shut down functions I kept the same but I changed `Pop()`  to check 
`if(running || !mList.empty())`
I also had to change the WriteWithThread to have 
```while (mProgramRunning|| !mList.empty())
 {
  auto list = Pop();
  if (list.empty())
  {
   continue;
  }
  else 
  {
   Write(list.front());
  }
 }```